# How to prevent from updating the record in sql which is used in another table?

Tags: sql

Tables

- `Country` (country_id, country_name)
- `Company` (company_id, country_id, Company_name)

How to prevent updating the row in the `country` table which is used in `Company` table?

Comment: Which DBML are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent updating"? If you use primary keys and foreign keys you can always update the country_name without any effect on Company.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE country SET your_values_here
WHERE 
countryId = 123 AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Company WHERE countryId = 123)

Comment: this is correct if country id is exist only one or two table...if country id exist more than 15-20 table then i have to check each n every table manually which is not suitable idea...

Comment: Well you'd only have to write the proc once.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use stored procedure to do that, Here's the pseudo code:

First, check if the countryID exists in Company

```
select 1 from Company where country_id = @country_id
```

If exist, throw an error, else do update:

```
update country set your_values_here
```

Comment: this is correct if country id is exist only one or two table...if country id exist more than 15-20 table then i have to check each n every table manually which is not suitable idea...

Answer (score 0):

Company::country_id is just a posted foreign key so an update to one table shouldn't affect the other.

Are you talking about insertions or deletes? If so you would either alter Company so that country_id can be null (i.e. not requiring a corresponding record in Country table) or you would turn off cascading deletes.

Hopefully one of those and Google will sort it for you.